# Generating random roads

Tags: java, algorithm, graph-algorithm

I am trying to generate random roads on a swing application. However, I am unable to create the roads such that they do not over-intersect with each other. I mean one road should not cross over another unless they have a common intersection point.

I tried generating random points and connecting them using minimum spanning trees but it does not seem to work.

Do you have any ideas?

Comment: What went wrong with the minimum spanning tree approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try the easy thing first: generate a bunch of random roads and keep only those that don't intersect any you've found so far. This has `O(n^2)` runtime, but it's easy to understand and implement.

In pseudocode:

```
points = (lots of random points)
roads = empty list
repeat n times:
  r = road(pick_random(points), pick_random(points))
  if r does not intersect anything in roads list:
    add r to roads
```

This has the advantage over minimum spanning trees that it may generate cycles for you, which would make for a more interesting road network.